# Android sdk option missing on android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android-studio, react-native, android-sdk-2.3

I have just downloaded the android studio from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).
I couldn't find the Android sdk option with this setup file. Can anyone help me with this problem?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Android sdk is already included when you install Android Studio, then if you want to download more sdk version, build tools,.. just use [SDK Manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager) tool

Comment: Yes, android sdk should be included but I can't see that option there. You can see the screenshot i share above.

Comment: Why you need this options? You want to exclude it or what?

Comment: I was expecting sdk on initial setup too. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: @NIteshShrestha yes, just install Android Studio and everything will be OK. Hope you get what you want ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can download sdk tool from the same page. Install the AS 2.3.3(it includes sdk)，then install 3.0.1, then put the sdk tool into the sdk folder.